# Where is the code for SL4 plugin for Sonar?

Tags: silverlight, sonarqube

I just found out that, Sonar does not support Silverlight 5, but it does support Silverlight 4. I thought, if I can take a look at Sl4 plugin code and I might able to add Silverlight 5 support. I was going through [plugin library](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library) but I can't find where is the SL4 plug in code. Could someone point me to where is it hosted and any direction in adding support for SL5. If the work is already in progress, how do I go about help on this project.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support of Silverlight is implemented in the .Net Core Plugin of the [.Net & C# Plugins Ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugins+Ecosystem).

Adding support for SL5 should be quite easy and should be only located on the [DotNetConstants class](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet/blob/master/sonar/dotnet/sonar-dotnet-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/dotnet/api/DotNetConstants.java).

If you manage to do what you want, feel free to open a pull request on the projet! :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, I am going to work on it. If I am able to do it, I will update.

Comment: The link to >net & C# Plugin Ecosystem is broken.

Comment: Got the code and made the changes to make SL5 work. I will work on how to pull request for the changes.

Comment: I opened a pull request with the changes. I am able to run SL5 under sonar with snapshot jar files. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take care of that.

Comment: I updated the corresponding JIRA ticket: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-292